# Problems with if (!IsPostBack) in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview and some columns are editable text fields and another column is a button in a template field with a command name(ED).

I have an issue with the postbacks because when I type next text into the textboxes I need to be able to click the save button and save the new data for the gridview and in order to do that I need the if (!IsPostBack) in the page load around my populategridview to stop it overwriting my changed data.

This would work fine but now when clicking my button it does not hit the command name and the button just disappears instead of doing anything. If I remove the if (!IsPostBack) the button works fine but I can't get the newly entered text data.

Here is some of my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetUserInfo();
    constPageID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["PageID"]);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGridview();
    }
}


private void PopulateGridview()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_UserColumns_Get", conn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageID", constPageID);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", strUserID);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                gvOrder.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                gvOrder.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
    }
}


protected void gvOrder_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ED")
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
        Label ID = gvr.FindControl("lblID") as Label;
        string id = ID.Text;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = GetConnection.GetConnectionString();
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("PL_UserColumns_ED", dbConnection);
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@PageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(constPageID);
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(strUserID);
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ColumnID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(id);
            dbConnection.Open();
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
        }

        Response.Redirect("ModifyColumns.aspx?&PageID=" + constPageID);

    }
}
}
```

Row Databound:

```
protected void gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            int index = 1;
            int indexenabled = 1;

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;
                txt = e.Row.FindControl("txtNewT") as TextBox;
            }
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add("1");
                ddl.Enabled = false;
                txt.Enabled = false;

            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex != 0)
            {
                ddl.Items.Remove("1");
                //Create ED button

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Button btnED = new Button();
                    btnED.ID = "btnED";
                    btnED.CssClass = "buttonsmall";
                    btnED.CommandName = "ED";
                    btnED.EnableViewState = true;

                    DataRow r = dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex];
                    if (r.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        btnED.Text = "Disable";
                        e.Row.CssClass = "RowEnabled";
                        foreach (DataRow r2 in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            if (r2.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "1")
                            {

                                string listitem = Convert.ToString(indexenabled+1);
                                ddl.Items.Add(listitem);
                                indexenabled++;                               
                            }

                        }
                        int itemtoremove = ddl.Items.Count+1;
                        ddl.Items.Remove(itemtoremove.ToString());

                        ddl.SelectedIndex = idxselected;
                        idxselected++;
                    }
                    else if (r.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        btnED.Text = "Enable";
                        e.Row.CssClass = "RowDisabled";
                        ddl.Enabled = false;
                        txt.Enabled = false;

                        foreach (DataRow r1 in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            string listitem = Convert.ToString(index);
                            ddl.Items.Add(listitem);
                            index++;
                        }
                        ddl.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
                    }

                    //Add button to grid
                    e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(btnED);
                }
            }
        }
        protected void btnED_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Coding to click event
        }
        protected void GetUserInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                if (UserInfo == null)
                {
                    //Sorry...no cookie!
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInfo.Values["UserID"]))
                    {
                        strUserID = UserInfo.Values["UserID"];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandling.NETException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
            }
        }
```

ASPX:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrder" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="tblBrowse" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvOrder_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvOrder_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentO" HeaderText="Curr. Order" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Order">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewO" runat="server" Width="99%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentT" HeaderText="Curr. Text" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Text">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="98%" ID="txtNewT" Text='<%# Bind("CurrentT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblED" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Enabled") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enable/Disable"></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="smallButton" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" Width="100px" OnClientClick="Close(); return true;" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you give us your aspx code?

Comment: You need to populate the grid on each postback. Remove the if (!IsPostBack) and see what happens.

Comment: @peer As I said, when I remove it the button does nothing.

Comment: @pinoy_ISF I have added the aspx.

Comment: I am not seeing any CommandField or the Button that has the CommandName "ED"?

Comment: It is setup dynamically in the code-behind, there is too much code to put all of it in here but the commandname works fine without the postback.

Comment: Have you considered using an `UpdatePanel` or `AJAX` to trigger the save or limit the data posted to the server rather than performing a full postback? Also you should be aware that not all items are persisted on postback, you should consider looking into details regarding the `ViewState` and other methods of control persistence as you might find your inputs aren't actually returned as you would expect.

Comment: I havnt considered it, I don't have much experience with those controls. What I am finding frustrating is that I can get the two functionalities to work, just not both at the same time due to the postback check, otherwise I would not be having any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to add a button dynamically so every time you have to construct that column separately. Since you are using `gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` this method will not be called in post back as you are not doing any gvOrder databinding in the post back, thus your buttons will be missed as they are added under the RowDataBound event.

Try the below code and check if it is working fine:

Page_load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetUserInfo();
    constPageID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["PageID"]);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGridview();
    }
    contructColumn();
}
```

Row data bound method:

```
protected void gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            contructColumn();
        }
```

Construct Column method (newly added method):

```
private void contructColumn()
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            int index = 1;
            int indexenabled = 1;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvOrder.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    ddl = row.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;
                    txt = row.FindControl("txtNewT") as TextBox;
                }
                if (row.RowIndex == 0)
                {
                    ddl.Items.Add("1");
                    ddl.Enabled = false;
                    txt.Enabled = false;

                }
                else if (row.RowIndex != 0)
                {
                    ddl.Items.Remove("1");
                    //Create ED button

                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        Button btnED = new Button();
                        btnED.ID = "btnED"+row.RowIndex;
                        btnED.CssClass = "buttonsmall";
                        btnED.CommandName = "ED";
                        btnED.EnableViewState = true;

                        DataRow r = dt.Rows[row.RowIndex];
                        if (r.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            btnED.Text = "Disable";
                            row.CssClass = "RowEnabled";
                            foreach (DataRow r2 in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (r2.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "1")
                                {

                                    string listitem = Convert.ToString(indexenabled + 1);
                                    ddl.Items.Add(listitem);
                                    indexenabled++;
                                }

                            }
                            int itemtoremove = ddl.Items.Count + 1;
                            ddl.Items.Remove(itemtoremove.ToString());

                            ddl.SelectedIndex = idxselected;
                            idxselected++;
                        }
                        else if (r.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "0")
                        {
                            btnED.Text = "Enable";
                            row.CssClass = "RowDisabled";
                            ddl.Enabled = false;
                            txt.Enabled = false;

                            foreach (DataRow r1 in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                string listitem = Convert.ToString(index);
                                ddl.Items.Add(listitem);
                                index++;
                            }
                            ddl.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;
                        }

                        //Add button to grid
                        row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(btnED);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @connersz: did u try the above or had any issues while doing?

Comment: Hi, I tried and I get an error when opening the page: Multiple controls with the same ID 'btnED' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: On this code: Line 52:                     ddl = row.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;

Comment: can you check the edited answer. I have just made one change in the above code. Changed the line 'btnED.ID = "btnED";' with 'btnED.ID = "btnED"+row.RowIndex;'

Comment: Tried and now get this instead: Multiple controls with the same ID 'btnED1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Can you try removing the 'gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)' method and check if it is working fine?

Comment: @connersz :Can you try removing the 'gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)' method and check if it is working fine?

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the update to the grid on the page prerender event, like so:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGridview();
    }

}
```

The ASP.NET page life cycle isn't always straight forward. See this from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I tried this, the button stays but it does not hit the RowCommand method.

Comment: That is because you really need to consider the page life cycle. You should dynamically create your buttons in the Page Init event because right after this event the Events are created...if your buttons do not exist by the time the Page Init event finishes, events are not created for them and so your RowCommand will never fire. I would strongly recommend putting the buttons into your asp.net markup for the page. For more info on dynamic controls check out this article: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/insights/750415-how-use-dynamic-controls-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

If `ModifyColumns.aspx` is the same page where all the code you posted lies then it is also one of the evident design flaws.

You need to replace:

```
Response.Redirect("ModifyColumns.aspx?&PageID=" + constPageID);
```

With

```
PopulateGridview();
```

in `gvOrder_RowCommand` method.

Other than that I am not sure if I completely understand what you are trying to achieve in `gvOrder_RowDataBound` method, but I think that what you are trying to achieve could be done without having to add controls dynamically. When adding dynamic controls you need to be cautious about recreating them at the right time, and dynamic controls should be avoided when using server controls already (it increases the complexity two folds). More over the grid view control provides a rich set of features to achieve a wide variety of functionalities.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the `EnableViewState` property to `true`, explicitly? It seems to me that your problem is due to the need to maintain your `ViewState` data, yet no one has touched on this point yet. Try adding `EnableViewState="true"` to your `GridView` control and see if the issue is resolved.

`True` is the default value of the property, but it is possible that it is being overridden elsewhere. I am a fan of covering my base-cases first :)